# How Java compilation works?

Tags: java, compilation

I have a question about java compilation or sequence of java file compilation.

Question - I have a small object oriented program where I have three classes. I wrote java code for the biggest one where I am creating the objects for other two classes and invoking the methods from other two classes. other two classes are very small. When I compiled the first class file (without writing other two class files), I got few compilation error messages. Then I wrote both new class files (but I didn't compile them, only .java files), my first class file compiled fine.

--So I want to understand, do I need to compile all the Java files to get all object references in those classes working or just writing java files is fine to compile any of these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compile the one that refers to all the others, they will be compiled automatically as soon as Compiler encounters them in your code.

Comment: Thanks Shashank, it means if I have all 3 files(Java) and I compile one of them it will compile all three, and it seems that you are right, it automatically compiled one file, but the class with main is not compiled...

Comment: If you have file1.java which refers to file2.java and file3.java, then  compiling file1 will automatically compile file2 and file3

Answer (score 0):

I would use a build system like maven, ant or your IDEs build system.  This means you don't need to worry about these issues.

In answer to your question; it depends.  You often don't need to compile everything, javac can compile more than one source file at once, sometimes you have to rebuild dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Peter, It is just starting so want to learn from the ground up, I will start using maven and other build system in some time.

Comment: IMHO that's learning the hard way. I would prefer learning to program in Java than learning how to use the tools. ;)